# Apply SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes only to particular paths

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Can you apply the `SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes` option to only a particular path pattern, e.g., `.../v3/...`?

We've gone through the trouble of enabling nullable contexts throughout our code, and ensuring all our parameters have the correct nullability. Now we want to utilize that for API validation. But since we don't want break any of our exising API behavior, we only want to apply the implicit Required attribute behvaior on paths for particular API versions. I.e., v2 would NOT have the validation, but v3+ would.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show you the way, but you have to walk through it and complete the implementation!

Ok, to see how `SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes` works, let's check the source code first!
Here's when the parameter is being used in `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider` class.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ea008c80d5cc63de7f90ddfd6823b7b006251ff/src/Mvc/Mvc.DataAnnotations/src/DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider.cs#L343

Now let's see where `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider` is used! It is added as a `ModelMetadataDetailsProviders` to `MvcOptions.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders`.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ea008c80d5cc63de7f90ddfd6823b7b006251ff/src/Mvc/Mvc.DataAnnotations/src/DependencyInjection/MvcDataAnnotationsMvcOptionsSetup.cs#L54

So you would need to create your own `CustomValidationMetadataProvider` and add it to `MvcOptions`.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(op =>
{
    op.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new CustomValidationMetadataProvider());
});

public class CustomValidationMetadataProvider : IValidationMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        // context.ValidationMetadata.IsRequired = ???
    }
}
```

Here you can have your own logic to set `context.ValidationMetadata.IsRequired`. Unfortunately I'm not sure if you can access the request path here, but you do have access to attributes on the model. So theoretically you could add an attribute to the models on your v3.

Comment: I won't be able to test this strategy out for a bit, but it seems like it would work. I'll report back when I give it a try. Thanks much.

Comment: Sorry to hijack this somewhat, but in this example how would you pass parameters to `CustomValidationMetadataProvider` that it expected to be injected by DI? I'm trying to do exactly this, but my custom provider needs a database context (which I've also added to the DI container) to be injected but I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I could suggest here:

1. If you on C# 8 you can try nullable properties/fields for places where you want to allow nullable values. (recommended simplest one)
2. You can use custom Parameter Binding (non-trivial approach). You can find more details here https://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/
3. You can disable standard model validation and provide your own (where you should be able to specify path) and again non-trivial approach.

Comment: Thx. We're already using nullable properties/fields. We want to apply validation based on the nullability of those files, but only for certain paths. `SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes` applies the validation, but on all paths.